# Dynamic Query in Elastic NEST

Tags: c#, elasticsearch, nest

So I have manually built the following Query in NEST which works correctly,
What im trying to figure out is a way to build this dynamically dependent on what Product Specification Filters are passed in

```
.Query(q => q                
            .MultiMatch(m => m
                .Query(searchBox.Text + "*")
                .Fields(ff => ff
                    .Field(f => f.Name, boost: nameBoost)
                    .Field(f => f.Description, boost: descriptionBoost)
                    .Field(f => f.ProductCode)))
        && q.Nested(n => n
            .Path(p => p.ProductSpecification)
            .Query(q2 => q2                   
                .Terms(t => t
                    .Field(f => f.ProductSpecification.Suffix("name"))
                    .Terms("Guarantee")
                    )).Query(q3 => q3
                        .Terms(t2 => t2
                            .Field(f2 => f2.ProductSpecification.Suffix("value"))
                            .Terms("3 years")
                            )))
        && q.Nested(n => n
            .Path(p => p.ProductSpecification)
            .Query(q2 => q2
                .Terms(t => t
                    .Field(f => f.ProductSpecification.Suffix("name"))
                    .Terms("Brand")
                    )).Query(q3 => q3
                        .Terms(t2 => t2
                            .Field(f2 => f2.ProductSpecification.Suffix("value"))
                            .Terms("Sony")
                            )))
```

After looking at the link that Russ has shared I think the solution is to pass in my filters

```
public class ElasticJsonFilter
{
    public string name { get; set; }
    public List<string> Values { get; set; } = new List<string>();
}
```

Which will give me names such as "Guarantee" and values such as "2 Years, 3 Years" looking at the code that Russ linked I can get his to run through my list of filters and spit out boolean filters but I guess I need to get this to build a nested query?

```
elasticParams.Filters.Aggregate(new QueryContainer(), (c, s) => c && +q.Term(p => p.Name, s), c => c);
```

Comment: Split it out into methods. Take a look at https://github.com/elastic/elasticsearch-net-example/blob/5.x-codecomplete-netcore-modifications/src/NuSearch.Web/Modules/Search/Search/SearchController.cs#L19-L25 as an example

Comment: Looks interesting Russ, thanks experimenting now

Comment: So I have been looking at the FilterTagSelection from the link you shared. Can the bool filters have name/value pairs eg like I have name:Guarantee value:3years like above

Comment: Have updated question